# Starting OpenVPN server with large number of connected clients Ubuntu

Tags: openvpn, scale

I have a single OpenVPN server instance running on a box running Ubuntu with a large number of clients (~500) connected over UDP. The client connections are stable till I restart the OpenVPN service on the server side. After that, the clients keep connecting and disconnecting, never able to achieve the same number of connections again. What could be the reason ? The connections on the client side keep timing out, never receiving any replies to their initial messages. Logs from one of the clients:

```
Wed Apr 22 10:16:14 2020 us=209975 [31956] Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1570 D:138 EF:38 EB:0 ET:0 EL:0 ]
Wed Apr 22 10:16:14 2020 us=210010 [31956] Socket Buffers: R=[229376->131072] S=[229376->131072]
Wed Apr 22 10:16:14 2020 us=210029 [31956] Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1570 D:1450 EF:70 EB:135 ET:0 EL:0 AF:3/1 ]
Wed Apr 22 10:16:14 2020 us=210052 [31956] Local Options String: 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1570,tun-mtu 1500,proto UDPv4,comp-lzo,cipher AES-128-CBC,auth SHA256,keysize 128,key-method 2,tls-client'
Wed Apr 22 10:16:14 2020 us=210060 [31956] Expected Remote Options String: 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1570,tun-mtu 1500,proto UDPv4,comp-lzo,cipher AES-128-CBC,auth SHA256,keysize 128,key-method 2,tls-server'
Wed Apr 22 10:16:14 2020 us=210074 [31956] Local Options hash (VER=V4): 'ec542dd5'
Wed Apr 22 10:16:14 2020 us=210087 [31956] Expected Remote Options hash (VER=V4): '00bc425f'
Wed Apr 22 10:16:14 2020 us=210098 [31956] UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Wed Apr 22 10:16:14 2020 us=210107 [31956] UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]10.146.23.218:8443
Wed Apr 22 10:16:14 2020 us=210130 [31956] UDPv4 WRITE [14] to [AF_INET]10.146.23.218:8443: P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_CLIENT_V2 kid=0 [ ] pid=0 DATA len=0
Wed Apr 22 10:16:16 2020 us=460234 [31956] UDPv4 WRITE [14] to [AF_INET]10.146.23.218:8443: P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_CLIENT_V2 kid=0 [ ] pid=0 DATA len=0
Wed Apr 22 10:16:20 2020 us=957985 [31956] UDPv4 WRITE [14] to [AF_INET]10.146.23.218:8443: P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_CLIENT_V2 kid=0 [ ] pid=0 DATA len=0
Wed Apr 22 10:16:28 2020 us=968424 [31956] UDPv4 WRITE [14] to [AF_INET]10.146.23.218:8443: P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_CLIENT_V2 kid=0 [ ] pid=0 DATA len=0
Wed Apr 22 10:16:44 2020 us=729143 [31956] UDPv4 WRITE [14] to [AF_INET]10.146.23.218:8443: P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_CLIENT_V2 kid=0 [ ] pid=0 DATA len=0
Wed Apr 22 10:17:16 2020 us=330992 [31956] UDPv4 WRITE [14] to [AF_INET]10.146.23.218:8443: P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_CLIENT_V2 kid=0 [ ] pid=0 DATA len=0
Wed Apr 22 10:18:20 2020 us=293321 [31956] UDPv4 WRITE [14] to [AF_INET]10.146.23.218:8443: P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_CLIENT_V2 kid=0 [ ] pid=0 DATA len=0
Wed Apr 22 10:19:14 2020 us=324898 [31956] [UNDEF] Inactivity timeout (--ping-restart), restarting
Wed Apr 22 10:19:14 2020 us=325114 [31956] TCP/UDP: Closing socket
Wed Apr 22 10:19:14 2020 us=325172 [31956] SIGUSR1[soft,ping-restart] received, process restarting
Wed Apr 22 10:19:14 2020 us=325217 [31956] Restart pause, 10 second(s)
```

And sometimes, it goes a few steps ahead and then times out:

```
Wed Apr 22 10:00:18 2020 us=961904 [31956] UDPv4 WRITE [14] to [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443: P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_CLIENT_V2 kid=0 [ ] pid=0 DATA len=0
Wed Apr 22 10:00:22 2020 us=447412 [31956] UDPv4 READ [26] from [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_SERVER_V2 kid=0 [ 0 ] pid=0 DATA len=0
Wed Apr 22 10:00:22 2020 us=447487 [31956] TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2), sid=99bdf93f 4d4f0c73
Wed Apr 22 10:00:22 2020 us=447606 [31956] UDPv4 WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 0 ]
Wed Apr 22 10:00:22 2020 us=447813 [31956] UDPv4 WRITE [114] to [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=1 DATA len=100
Wed Apr 22 10:00:22 2020 us=447990 [31956] UDPv4 WRITE [114] to [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=2 DATA len=100
Wed Apr 22 10:00:22 2020 us=448131 [31956] UDPv4 WRITE [100] to [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=3 DATA len=86
Wed Apr 22 10:00:24 2020 us=789806 [31956] UDPv4 WRITE [114] to [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): 
...
...
Wed Apr 22 10:00:29 2020 us=952755 [31956] UDPv4 READ [126] from [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ 3 ] pid=1 DATA len=100
Wed Apr 22 10:00:29 2020 us=952860 [31956] UDPv4 WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 1 ]
Wed Apr 22 10:00:29 2020 us=952978 [31956] UDPv4 READ [114] from [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=2 DATA len=100
Wed Apr 22 10:00:29 2020 us=953016 [31956] UDPv4 WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 2 ]
Wed Apr 22 10:00:29 2020 us=953074 [31956] UDPv4 READ [114] from [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=3 DATA len=100
Wed Apr 22 10:00:29 2020 us=953107 [31956] UDPv4 WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 3 ]
Wed Apr 22 10:00:29 2020 us=953168 [31956] UDPv4 READ [114] from [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=4 DATA len=100
Wed Apr 22 10:00:29 2020 us=953201 [31956] UDPv4 WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 4 ]
Wed Apr 22 10:00:30 2020 us=411565 [31956] UDPv4 READ [22] from [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 1 ]
Wed Apr 22 10:00:36 2020 us=566024 [31956] UDPv4 READ [126] from [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ 1 ] pid=1 DATA len=100
Wed Apr 22 10:00:36 2020 us=566119 [31956] UDPv4 WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 1 ]
Wed Apr 22 10:00:36 2020 us=566243 [31956] UDPv4 READ [114] from [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=2 DATA len=100
Wed Apr 22 10:00:36 2020 us=566302 [31956] UDPv4 WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 2 ]
Wed Apr 22 10:00:36 2020 us=566396 [31956] UDPv4 READ [114] from [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=3 DATA len=100
Wed Apr 22 10:00:36 2020 us=566450 [31956] UDPv4 WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 3 ]
Wed Apr 22 10:00:36 2020 us=566657 [31956] UDPv4 READ [114] from [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=4 DATA len=100
Wed Apr 22 10:00:36 2020 us=566769 [31956] UDPv4 WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 4 ]
Wed Apr 22 10:00:38 2020 us=981036 [31956] UDPv4 READ [114] from [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=5 DATA len=100
Wed Apr 22 10:00:38 2020 us=981102 [31956] UDPv4 WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 5 ]
Wed Apr 22 10:00:38 2020 us=981167 [31956] UDPv4 READ [114] from [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=6 DATA len=100
Wed Apr 22 10:00:38 2020 us=981204 [31956] UDPv4 WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 6 ]
Wed Apr 22 10:00:38 2020 us=981286 [31956] UDPv4 READ [114] from [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=7 DATA len=100
Wed Apr 22 10:00:38 2020 us=981328 [31956] UDPv4 WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 7 ]
Wed Apr 22 10:00:38 2020 us=981371 [31956] UDPv4 READ [114] from [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=8 DATA len=100
Wed Apr 22 10:00:38 2020 us=981406 [31956] UDPv4 WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 8 ]
Wed Apr 22 10:00:49 2020 us=79299 [31956] UDPv4 READ [114] from [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=6 DATA len=100
Wed Apr 22 10:00:49 2020 us=79459 [31956] UDPv4 WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 6 ]
Wed Apr 22 10:00:49 2020 us=79750 [31956] UDPv4 READ [114] from [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=7 DATA len=100
Wed Apr 22 10:00:49 2020 us=79874 [31956] UDPv4 WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 7 ]
Wed Apr 22 10:00:49 2020 us=80081 [31956] UDPv4 READ [114] from [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=8 DATA len=100
Wed Apr 22 10:00:49 2020 us=80191 [31956] UDPv4 WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 8 ]
Wed Apr 22 10:00:49 2020 us=80388 [31956] UDPv4 READ [114] from [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=9 DATA len=100
Wed Apr 22 10:00:49 2020 us=80507 [31956] UDPv4 WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 9 ]
Wed Apr 22 10:00:49 2020 us=80636 [31956] UDPv4 READ [114] from [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=10 DATA len=100
Wed Apr 22 10:00:49 2020 us=80717 [31956] UDPv4 WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 10 ]
Wed Apr 22 10:00:49 2020 us=80884 [31956] UDPv4 READ [114] from [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=11 DATA len=100
Wed Apr 22 10:00:49 2020 us=80977 [31956] UDPv4 WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 11 ]
Wed Apr 22 10:00:49 2020 us=81130 [31956] UDPv4 READ [114] from [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=12 DATA len=100
...
...
Wed Apr 22 10:00:59 2020 us=796622 [31956] UDPv4 WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 15 ]
Wed Apr 22 10:00:59 2020 us=796741 [31956] UDPv4 READ [114] from [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=16 DATA len=100
Wed Apr 22 10:00:59 2020 us=796788 [31956] UDPv4 WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 16 ]
Wed Apr 22 10:00:59 2020 us=796885 [31956] UDPv4 READ [114] from [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=17 DATA len=100
Wed Apr 22 10:00:59 2020 us=796933 [31956] UDPv4 WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 17 ]
Wed Apr 22 10:00:59 2020 us=797016 [31956] UDPv4 READ [114] from [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=18 DATA len=100
Wed Apr 22 10:00:59 2020 us=797061 [31956] UDPv4 WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 18 ]
Wed Apr 22 10:00:59 2020 us=797139 [31956] UDPv4 READ [114] from [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=19 DATA len=100
Wed Apr 22 10:00:59 2020 us=797172 [31956] UDPv4 WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 19 ]
Wed Apr 22 10:00:59 2020 us=797271 [31956] UDPv4 READ [114] from [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=20 DATA len=100
Wed Apr 22 10:00:59 2020 us=797313 [31956] UDPv4 WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 20 ]
Wed Apr 22 10:01:08 2020 us=418632 [31956] UDPv4 READ [114] from [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=17 DATA len=100
Wed Apr 22 10:01:08 2020 us=418683 [31956] UDPv4 WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 17 ]
Wed Apr 22 10:01:08 2020 us=418754 [31956] UDPv4 READ [114] from [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=18 DATA len=100
Wed Apr 22 10:01:08 2020 us=418794 [31956] UDPv4 WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 18 ]
Wed Apr 22 10:01:08 2020 us=418848 [31956] UDPv4 READ [114] from [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=19 DATA len=100
Wed Apr 22 10:01:08 2020 us=418876 [31956] UDPv4 WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 19 ]
Wed Apr 22 10:01:08 2020 us=418929 [31956] UDPv4 READ [114] from [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=20 DATA len=100
Wed Apr 22 10:01:08 2020 us=418960 [31956] UDPv4 WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 20 ]
Wed Apr 22 10:01:08 2020 us=419048 [31956] UDPv4 READ [114] from [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=21 DATA len=100
Wed Apr 22 10:01:08 2020 us=419097 [31956] UDPv4 WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 21 ]
Wed Apr 22 10:01:08 2020 us=419170 [31956] UDPv4 READ [114] from [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=22 DATA len=100
Wed Apr 22 10:01:08 2020 us=419220 [31956] UDPv4 WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 22 ]
Wed Apr 22 10:01:08 2020 us=419298 [31956] UDPv4 READ [114] from [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=23 DATA len=100
Wed Apr 22 10:01:08 2020 us=419348 [31956] UDPv4 WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 23 ]
Wed Apr 22 10:01:08 2020 us=419416 [31956] UDPv4 READ [114] from [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=24 DATA len=100
Wed Apr 22 10:01:08 2020 us=419449 [31956] UDPv4 WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 24 ]
Wed Apr 22 10:01:16 2020 us=361894 [31956] UDPv4 READ [114] from [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=21 DATA len=100
Wed Apr 22 10:01:16 2020 us=361993 [31956] UDPv4 WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 21 ]
Wed Apr 22 10:01:16 2020 us=362261 [31956] UDPv4 READ [114] from [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=22 DATA len=100
Wed Apr 22 10:01:16 2020 us=362341 [31956] UDPv4 WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 22 ]
Wed Apr 22 10:01:16 2020 us=362585 [31956] UDPv4 READ [114] from [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=23 DATA len=100
Wed Apr 22 10:01:16 2020 us=362643 [31956] UDPv4 WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 23 ]
Wed Apr 22 10:01:16 2020 us=362855 [31956] UDPv4 READ [114] from [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=24 DATA len=100
Wed Apr 22 10:01:16 2020 us=362910 [31956] UDPv4 WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 24 ]
Wed Apr 22 10:01:16 2020 us=363146 [31956] UDPv4 READ [114] from [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=25 DATA len=100
Wed Apr 22 10:01:16 2020 us=363213 [31956] UDPv4 WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 25 ]
Wed Apr 22 10:01:16 2020 us=363463 [31956] UDPv4 READ [114] from [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=26 DATA len=100
...
...
UDPv4 WRITE [114] to [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=10 DATA len=100
Wed Apr 22 10:02:10 2020 us=955007 [31956] UDPv4 READ [22] from [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 12 ]
Wed Apr 22 10:02:38 2020 us=998361 [31956] UDPv4 WRITE [114] to [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=9 DATA len=100
Wed Apr 22 10:02:40 2020 us=213582 [31956] UDPv4 WRITE [114] to [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=10 DATA len=100
Wed Apr 22 10:02:46 2020 us=59600 [31956] UDPv4 READ [22] from [AF_INET]10.146.7.218:8443 (via [AF_INET]10.146.7.195%Port2): P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 10 ]
Wed Apr 22 10:03:24 2020 us=700713 [31956] TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 200 seconds (check your network connectivity)
Wed Apr 22 10:03:24 2020 us=700760 [31956] TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Wed Apr 22 10:03:24 2020 us=700962 [31956] TCP/UDP: Closing socket
Wed Apr 22 10:03:24 2020 us=700992 [31956] SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
Wed Apr 22 10:03:24 2020 us=701025 [31956] Restart pause, 10 second(s)
```

Comment: The question is not clear. The client side connections time out when they try to connect to server side? And  whats the situation that require you to restart the server?

Comment: The server restart is one of the test that we have to do to qualify the maximum clients supported by the server. Yes, the client side keeps timing out. I have edited my question to post client logs

Answer (score 0):

Not enough reputation to comment, so I write here: Have you checked this?
[OpenVPN TLS handshake hangs at P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_SERVER_V2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/417113/openvpn-tls-handshake-hangs-at-p-control-hard-reset-server-v2-not-received)

Comment: I tried that and it did not help my situation

Comment: I think the problem is that openvpn waits synchronously when doing client connects. This causes packets to line up in its receive queue. Can we remove this synchronous wait which causes the openvpn to block completely while a client is connecting ?